# python - curve_fit - A non-int/float error

Tags: python, scipy

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x1 = [0.25, 0.33, 0.40, 0.50, 0.60, 0.75, 1.00]
y1 = [1.02, 1.39, 1.67, 1.89, 2.08, 2.44, 2.50]

def mmfunc(x1, d, e):
    return d*x1/(e + x1)

y2 = mmfunc(x1,6.0,1.0)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(mmfunc, x1, y1)
```

I get this error

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

(x1 is an array (floats), d, e are floats)

(I tried reading values from a file, printed the values (they are floats) ...
I tried a simpler function - nothing seems to work!)

Comment: What is unclear about the exception?

Comment: Can you put that in the form of a question?

Comment: The problem is that "x1 is an array (floats)" is not true. Instead of just assuming that it's what you want it to be, that should be the first thing you check. For example, `print(type(x1))` would immediately tell you that it's actually a `builtins.list`, not a `numpy.ndarray`. And therefore, you can't use array-specific operations on it.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're not converting your lists to numpy arrays, so you can't add to or multiply by scalars.  This seems to work for me:

```
import numpy as np

x1 = np.array([0.25, 0.33, 0.40, 0.50, 0.60, 0.75, 1.00], dtype="float")
y1 = np.array([1.02, 1.39, 1.67, 1.89, 2.08, 2.44, 2.50], dtype="float")

def mmfunc(x1, d, e):
    return d*x1/(e + x1)

y2 = mmfunc(x1,6.0,1.0)
```

(Note:  I didn't have `scipy` installed so I wasn't able to check that the curve_fit function works, but the conversion to `np.array` fixed the exception related to arithmetic on lists.)

Comment: thanks - yes, I did check (so I thought) x1 and y1 ... when I did print x1 - got the series of numbers (floats) ... but yes, this works - explicitly declaring them as floats - thanks again ...

Comment: Take note: this change is not about declaring them as floats, it's about turning a Python `list` object into a `numpy.array` object.  Those are two different things, and do not support the same operations!  Also, if my answer was helpful, consider marking it "accepted" to let other people know that. :)